# Start a process in a different console window

Tags: python

How can I start a process to run in a different console window using Python in Linux, something similar to this in windows(using start):

```
import os

os.system('start dir c:\*.* /s')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xterm](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm) -e should do the trick for you.

> **-e** program [ arguments ... ]
>
> This option specifies the program (and its command line arguments) to be
> run in the xterm window. It also sets
> the window title and icon name to be
> the basename of the program being
> executed if neither -T nor -n are
> given on the command line. This must
> be the last option on the command
> line.

E.g.

```
import os

os.system("xterm -e 'your command'")
```